# Как при hover показывать один элемент над другим?

Tags: html, javascript

Вообщем есть элемент. При наведении курсора на него надо показывать другой элемент над ним. Когда курсор улетает - убирать новый элемент. [Всё просто.](http://jsfiddle.net/4qgwM/)

Однако есть одна проблема - если быстро провести курсор через элемент, то устанавливается новый элемент, но не успевает убраться. **Как исправить?**

Comment: @mountpoint судя по всему есть. Как объяснить иначе, если он работает?

Comment: извините, точно есть. Вам надо чистым JS или jQuery тоже пойдет?

Comment: чистым js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ужос, вешать события через setAttribute.... как-то так должно сработать, (ie>=8) возможно задержку придется увеличить.

```
function show() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('style', 'background:yellow;width:25%;height:25%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;');
    div.onmouseout = hide;
    div.innerHTML = "div 2";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    setTimeout(function () {
        isHover(div) || hide.apply(div);
    }, 100);
}

function hide() {
    this.remove();
}

function isHover(e) {
    if (!e.parentElement) return true;
    return (e.parentElement.querySelector(':hover') === e);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/4ejHt/

ну и второе решение - делать элемент дочерним к первому div, а mouseout вешать на родителя.

Comment: мне вот всегда было интересно: чем больше строчек кода, тем круче программер?

Comment: не понял, вы считаете тут лишними какие-то строчки ? строчек кода тут не так уж и много, можно было сократить, но не хотел использовать прямой запрос к DOM в вызове hide. (можно и сократить чуток)

Comment: Спс, то что надо. Правда можно обмануть, если нажать правой мышкой внутри, то желтяк останется, но это пофиг.

Answer (score 1):

Как то так http://jsfiddle.net/NYAeM/

Comment: та же самая проблема, что и у меня 
> - если быстро провести курсор через элемент, то устанавливается новый элемент, но не успевает убраться.

Comment: @danpetruk, тогда css юзай - http://jsfiddle.net/ZEBLQ/. js при таком раскладе не покатит

Answer (score 1):

Для чего тут JS?
http://jsfiddle.net/ZEBLQ/

Comment: нужно элемент удалять, а не скрывать. как автор захотел, так и сделал))

Comment: Не подходит, child должен быть вне

Comment: Не думаю что автор имел ввиду именно "удалять объект из DOM"

Comment: @Олег Б, мною был замечен метод remove(). По этой причине я понял, что автор хочет именно удалять элемент из DOM

Comment: да нет проблем, держите

http://jsfiddle.net/SRHrV/1/

Comment: @Олег Б это почти подходит. А можно как-то, чтобы элемент генерировался и исчезал в DOM структуре?

Comment: если нужен DOM то только через JS как предложил товарищ @mountpoint но глюки с "быстрым" ховером останутся.

- Если только на timer(1) проверять положение курсора и если он вне зоны child, parent -> скрывать child, но это совсем "индус мод".

Answer (score 1):

Что за функция `remove();` о.О?

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1]; 
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
```

Comment: @lampa, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp хотя его юзают только в селектах)